# Navigate an XML sequentially

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Please teach me how to navigate an xml with php.

Have a look at http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/XML/C-42.xml.

I made my first attempts to use simplexml_load_file, but what it does is group all the data by tags, which is great at the lower level, but what I need is to preserve some linearity.

In other words, once I get inside , I need to know which Section follows which Heading, etc.

How would I go about that?

```
<?php
    $url="http://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/XML/C-42.xml";
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($url);

    echo $xml->Identification->LongTitle;
    echo "<br>";

    foreach ($xml->Body as $hd) {
           // WHAT DO I DO HERE?
    }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to add some code?

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this. It was a legitimate question showing some research and definitely useful to people who, like me, are only starting to figure out what simplexml is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over all children of an element in SimpleXML using [the `->children()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php).

`foreach ( $simple_xml_doc->children() as $tag ) { ... }` will give you a SimpleXML object for each child element, regardless of tag, in the order they appear in the original file.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Once I get the array of $tag's - is there a way to know from the inside of the $tag, whether it's a heading or a section? In other words, how do I know WHAT the tag actually is?

Comment: found answer to my question. I would do it with ->getName()